# Newline inside variable string

Tags: php, javascript, html

What if I have a long input of string? maybe 50-250 characters.
and I echoed the variable it would echo a very long line of letters and words.

So, how will I let the variable auto Newline itself? maybe after 50 characters it would new line when echoed.

I have thought of counting the length of the string and looping it and after counting 50 characters it would Newline but if i do that it would slow down the Site.

is there any function to Newline a `VARIABLE STRING`? or i should use Looping instead?

Comment: You don't need to insert newlines. If you're outputting into html it will automatically wrap within its containing element. If you're outputting into a JavaScript script block inside a string variable nobody will see the result anyway. (If you did want to do it anyway you don't necessarily need a loop, you could easily do it with a regex replace.) Note also that inserting a newline every x characters won't look right unless you use a monospace font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a built-in PHP function: [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap).

If you want to cut at 50 characters and insert a HTML line-break:
`wordrap($str, 50, "<br />");`
You can also use the last parameter to force return, even if the string does not contain spaces.

Comment: i tried wordwrap, but i can't make it work. is there something wrong with this line of codes? `<?php $str = $row_Personalinfo['hospitalized'];  $newstr = wordwrap($str,20,"<br />\n"); echo $newstr;?>`

Comment: It only works when you have space on your string. it helped me thanks.

Comment: Use the fourth parameter to force line break.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert escape characters into a string, such as `\n` which will be translated to a new line break.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PHP_EOL` in conjunction  with `strlen()` to acheive what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding more info about `\n`:

```
 // PHP 5.5.12

 // This works for outputing to browser:
 $XmlHeader = '<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>' . "\n";

 // These do NOT work:
 $XmlHeader = '<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>' . '\n';
 $XmlHeader = '<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>\n';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Correct this was not intended to answer the discriptive question. But if we just read the title of this question this answer might help someone in future. I only wanted to comment on other answer but couldn't because of  lack of rep.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage the string in php i think the definitive solution is using function wordwrap:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

You can set the max lenght of a row, the braek parameter (in your case /n).

The function returns a string with the /n breaks and you can print it.